# Is $AC[a,b]$ closed in $(BV[a,b],TV)$?

Tags: real-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, bounded-variation

Consider $BV[a,b]$ the space of all bounded variation functions on a real interval $[a,b]$, endowed with the total variation norm $TV$. $AC[a,b]$, the space of absolutely continuous functions, is a subspace of $BV$. Is it closed?

Comment: The total variation "norm" is not a norm.

Comment: I'm not sure of the relevance of  $BV[a,b] \subset L^1[a,b].$  The equivalence classes do not match up. Changing a BV function at one point can change it's BV norm, but is irrelevant for the L^1 norm.

Comment: @Ian By the way, your sequence $f_n$ is not Cauchy in BV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quantity $\|f\| = |f(a)| + \|f\|_{TV}$ is a natural norm on $BV[a,b].$ If $f\in AC,$ then this norm equals $|f(a)| + \int_a^b|f'|.$ Suppose $f_n$ is a sequence in $AC$ that is Cauchy in this norm. Then $f_n(a)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb R,$ and $f_n'$ is Cauchy in $L^1[a,b].$ Thus $f_n(a) \to c$ in $ \mathbb R$ and $f_n'\to g$ in $L^1[a,b].$ We find then that $f_n(x) \to  c + \int_a^x g$ in $BV.$ The last function is in $AC,$ proving $AC$ is closed in $BV.$

Comment: That seems to only work if $[a,b]\spse[0,1]$, But I guess I can just change the point from 0 to any point in the interval, and the limits of integration from $\int_0^1$ to \int_a^b$ to apply what you say in your answer to any interval. Right? Even infinite intervals perhaps?

Comment: Whoops, I am SO used to my LaTeX shortcuts that I typed `\spse` for `\supseteq` ($\supseteq$) above :). That is, $[a,b]\spse[0,1]$ meant $[a,b]\supseteq[0,1]$.

Comment: Yes, in my mind we were on $[0,1]$ all of a sudden. I'll edit.

Comment: Is it important to choose $a$ as opposed to any point in [a,b]? I would guess not.

Comment: @MickG No, any point in that interval will do.